# How to install Processing in Edubuntu 12.04

Tags: java

Can you help me, please?
I have Edubuntu installed in my computer and I need to install Processing. How can do it?
Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by Processing, is it a software name or a kind of software?

Comment: Processing is a programming language. [processing.org]

Comment: Thanks. I found that it is [both a programming language and IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language). It is quite interesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Download the PDE (Processing Development Environment) from [processing.org](http://processing.org/download/). Select the appropriate OS type such as 32bit or 64bit.
- Then extract the downloaded archive in your home directory. We assume it is in `~/processing` directory.
- Now execute `chmod +x ~/processing/processing` to give it execution permission.
- You can now run it from a terminal by using commands like this

  ```
  bash ~/processing/processing
  ```

Hope this help you.

<sup>[Reference: This wiki page on processing forum](http://forum.processing.org/topic/can-t-figure-out-how-to-install-processing-in-ubuntu).</sup>

Comment: Also [see this page](http://www.processing.org/learning/gettingstarted/) and let us know if it works

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.spacemig.com/installing-processing-in-ubuntu-12-04/) gives a very nice step by step approach (it is not as easy as earlier answer suggested, since pre-installed java does not work for procssing).

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @DrewNoakes fixed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.